# PHP DomDocument - How to replace a text from a Node with another node

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument, nodes

I have a node:

```
<p>
    This is a test node with Figure 1.
</p>
```

My goal is to replace "Figure 1" with a child node:

```
<xref>Figure 1</xref>
```

So that the final result will be:

```
<p>
    This is a test node with <xref>Figure 1</xref>.
</p>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xpath allows you to fetch the text nodes containing the string from the document. Then you have to split it into a list of text and element (xref) nodes and insert that nodes before the text node. Last remove the original text node.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<p>
    This is a test node with Figure 1.
</p>
XML;
$string = 'Figure 1';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// find text nodes that contain the string
$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//text()[contains(., "'.$string.'")]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  // explode the text at the string
  $parts = explode($string, $node->nodeValue);
  // add a new text node with the first part
  $node->parentNode->insertBefore(
    $dom->createTextNode(
      // fetch and remove the first part from the list
      array_shift($parts)
    ),
    $node
  );
  // if here are more then one part
  foreach ($parts as $part) {
    // add a xref before it
    $node->parentNode->insertBefore(
      $xref = $dom->createElement('xref'),
      $node
    );
    // with the string that we used to split the text
    $xref->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($string));
    // add the part from the list as new text node
    $node->parentNode->insertBefore(
      $dom->createTextNode($part), 
      $node
    );
  }
  // remove the old text node
  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
} 

echo $dom->saveXml($dom->documentElement);
```

Output:

```
<p>
    This is a test node with <xref>Figure 1</xref>.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first use [`getElementsByTagName()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) to find the node you're looking for and remove the search text from the `nodeValue` of that node. Now, create the new node, set the `nodeValue` as the search text and append the new node to the main node:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<p>This is a test node with Figure 1</p>');

$searchFor = 'Figure 1';

// replace the searchterm in given paragraph node
$p_node = $dom->getElementsByTagName("p")->item(0);
$p_node->nodeValue = str_replace($searchFor, '', $p_node->nodeValue);

// create the new element
$new_node = $dom->createElement("xref");
$new_node->nodeValue = $searchFor;

// append the child element to paragraph node
$p_node->appendChild($new_node);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<p>This is a test node with <xref>Figure 1</xref></p>
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/79164)

Comment: I am reopening this question because the code will not realy replace a given text with a node: the created node is always added at the end of the $paragraph node, so if I add something after the Figure 1, then the code is not working anymore.